# remove chunks of word from string

Tags: java, replace

In java i have to cut word "getenforce" from string.

problem is the word I receive is sometimes cut off. For example i receive "etenforce", or "tenforc".

I could assume at least 4 letters will come in and filter it like that:

```
//st ---> this is string
st = st.replace("getenforce", "");
st = st.replace("gete", "");
st = st.replace("eten", "");
st = st.replace("tenf", "");
...
st = st.replace("orce", "");
```

is there some better, more elegant way?

Comment: Unless you already know all cases in advance, no. You could use quantifiers in your regular expressions (right now your regular expressions are just literals for all known cases) but you might end up inadvertently strip out parts of your text you don't want to get rid of.

Comment: > at least 4 letters
So it could be also 5, 6 ... getenforce.length, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop instead of doing this line by line.

```
String theWord = "getenforce";
st = st.replace(theWord, "");
//check all the sequences in loop        
for(int i=0; i<theWord.length()-3;i++){
    st=st.replace(theWord.subSequence(i, i+4), "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will resolve your query

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("your sentence with word gete".split(" "));   
List<String> filtered = strings.stream().filter(s1 -> !s1.contains("gete")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```